# Transfer phonebook Samsung Galaxy S3 Android 4.3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, contacts, windows, data-transfer

1) How to save the phonebook on the computer ?
2) Transfer phonebook to a new phone (with my computer) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can backup your phonebook from your mobile and then transfer the .csv file to your computer and then back again into the new device.

Comment: Or, you can use bluetooth to transfer this .csv file from one phone to another directly. But yeah, may be OP necessarily wants 1.

Answer (score 1):

It's most simple to transfer your contacts to your Google account. Any new device you're adding to your Google account will synchronise and get the same contacts. This way you'll also have an online backup so in case your phone dies, you don't have to gather phone numbers.

To do so, follow these steps:

**STEP 1:**

On your phone, go to your contacts and press the menu icon.
Press "Import/Export", select "Export to storage" and press "OK"
A file on the root of your phone storage will be created called something like this: "`00001.vcf`" (this is called a [`vCard`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard))

**STEP 2:**

Go to the following URL on your phone (or computer, but you have to move over the `00001.vcf` file):
https://www.google.com/contacts/u/0/?cplus=0#contacts (note: you have to go to this url and not contacts.google.com. There's a preview going on which does not support importing contacts yet)

[image: Screenshot of the import function of Google Contacts]

Choose the file in the following popup and press "Import":

[image: Screenshot of the import contacts popup]

Now that you've uploaded and imported your contacts, you should see your contacts appear on your new phone.

If you've imported the contacts with your phone, you can see the contacts on either one of the following URLS on your computer:

https://www.google.com/contacts/u/0/?cplus=0#contacts

https://contacts.google.com/

Note: you should be logged into your Google account on your phone.

Comment: Thank you! But I do not want to shine contacts on Google...